# Why cannot Listen port 80 from port 3000 ? (Nginx)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nginx, server

I want to ask about configuration like this (I deploy web NodeJs + npm forever - I registered web using expressjs to port 3000):

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name domain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

why can't i change it to port 80 ? so the plan is I want to call port 3000 so that port 80 can be used. Before is success, but because I did the reset and now I can't anymore. please enlighten me :)

Comment: This isn't a programming question, [sf] would be a better place to ask about configuring NGINX.

Comment: What happens when you try to use port 80? Do you get an error? If so, what's the error?

Comment: ok thanks Barmar for your response. The results did not match expectations, because they issued an error (404) or could not be read. I tried it before and it worked, but when I reset it because there are several factors, the results fail when I try again.

Comment: Are there any error messages in the nginx logs? (In the setup I'm familiar with there are two log files, `access.log` and `error.log`, both in `/var/log/nginx/`, but I don't know whether this is a standard setup. Certainly the directory will be different if you're in Windows.)

Comment: there is no error message, it works properly. But port 80 was not found when I run it.

Comment: Could it be a permissions issue? I believe the operating system doesn't allow unprivileged processes to listen on ports less than 1000.

Comment: @DavidKnipe Maybe, ok I will try it